# How to handle a cycle in dbt?

Tags: cycle, dbt

I need to add delta data to table x. So, I need to create a cycle. I read table x, then I find the delta between the source and table x. After that, I insert the delta to table x. How to do this in dbt? Is it possible to break the cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change it from ref to source. so instead of using ref, I use source. I create another schema for the source. just to break the cycle in dbt. so basically, 1 table has ref and source at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is an incremental model, have a look at:
[incremental models in DBT](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models)

Comment: actually i use incremental model for this. well, one is incremental and one is replace table.

Comment: so you know what to do, ie. the incremental model delivers per definition exactly what you need. Namely: "
I need to add delta data to table x. So, I need to create a cycle. I read table x, then I find the delta between the source and table x. After that, I insert the delta to table x" so what is the missing part?

Comment: actually it’s solved. i manipulated the source and reference table

Comment: What specifically did you manipulate, and how did it resolve it? Can you post your resolution for other readers @colintobing

Comment: @colintobing can you please show the flow? I'm trying to read a log staging and update with new data.

Comment: @Claudiu I put the answer above. and marked it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

If the full scan approach is fine, then you can just create a query

```
select col1,col2, col2... from source_Table 
minus 
select col1,col2, col2... from x
```

this will give you all the records that are there in source_table but not in table x.

If the full scan is not fine, then you can need to make sure that you have updated_timestamp in your source table, and based on that you can write an incremental model.

Comment: it’s not working that way in dbt. since dbt has its own detection for lineage.

Comment: use incremental with this as ref : https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/this#:~:text=event_time)%20from-,%7B%7B%20this%20%7D%7D),-%7B%25%20endif